# I'm new to C and I am having a hard time with function computations

Tags: c, function

Basically we had an exercise to create a function that computes the monthly charge of an electricity bill wherein the first 100000 kwh will charge 0.05 then the exceeding kwh will charge 0.03 I did not complete the exercise and decided to practice this problem but I'm stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Aircon 261
#define Fan 12
#define TV 27
#define Ref 117

float computeTotalCharges(int usage, int consumption);

void main(){
    
    int qAircon, qFan, qTV, qRef, hAircon, hFan, hTV, hRef, usageHrs, kwh;
    float monthlyCharges;
    
    printf("Input qty of Aircon in Household: ");
    scanf("%d", &qAircon);
    printf("Input usage hrs per day: ");
    scanf("%d", &hAircon);
    printf("\nInput qty of Fan in Household: ");
    scanf("%d", &qFan);
    printf("Input usage hrs per day: ");
    scanf("%d", &hFan);
    printf("\nInput qty of TV in Household: ");
    scanf("%d", &qTV);
    printf("Input usage hrs per day: ");
    scanf("%d", &hTV);
    printf("\nInput qty of Refrigerator in Household: ");
    scanf("%d", &qRef);
    printf("Input usage hrs per day: ");
    scanf("%d", &hRef);
    
    usageHrs = (qAircon * hAircon) + (qFan * hFan) 
                + (qTV * hTV) + (qRef * hRef);
    
    kwh = ((qAircon * hAircon) * Aircon)+ ((qFan * hFan) * Fan) 
            + ((qTV * hTV) * TV) + ((qRef * hRef) * Ref);
    
    monthlyCharges = computeTotalCharges(usageHrs, kwh);
    
    printf("\nDescription\t\t\t    Qty\t    Hrs/Day\n");
    printf("Aircon \t\t\t\t%6d \t  %6d\n", qAircon, hAircon);
    printf("Fan \t\t\t\t%6d \t  %6d\n", qFan, hFan);
    printf("TV \t\t\t\t%6d \t  %6d\n", qTV, hTV);
    printf("Refrigerator \t\t\t%6d \t  %6d\n\n", qRef, hRef);
    printf("Total Usage(Hrs): \t\t\t  %6d\n", usageHrs);
    printf("Total Consumption(kwh): \t\t  %6d\n", kwh);
    printf("Total Charges: \t\tPesos \t\t %4.2f", monthlyCharges);
}

float computeTotalCharges(int usage, int consumption){
    
    int usageHrs1, kwh1;
    float monthlyBill;
    
    usageHrs1 = usage * 30;
    kwh1 = consumption * 30;
    monthlyBill = (kwh1 >= 100000) ? (100000 * 0.05) + ((kwh1 - 100000) * 0.03) 
                                            : kwh1 * 0.05;
        
    return monthlyBill; 
}
```

I only understood the how to compute if the consumption exceeds 100k part but for the computations of the usage and consumption I tried a lot of computations but I don't return a value for the monthly consumption and usage.

Edit: I put in my whole code. We were only allowed to use the ternary operator for the condition in the function and now I can't seem to return the value for usage and consumption when multiplied by 30.

Comment: I'm confused (also): what's the distinction between consumption and usage?

Comment: usage means the total usage hrs for the appliances and the consumption is the total kwh

Comment: You don't mention hours anywhere. Why do you have a parameter for that at all?

Comment: It's quite interesting how you get to the `(consumption >= 100000) ? (100000 * 0.05) + ((consumption - 100000) * 0.03) : consumption * 0.05` expression while you _'only understood the how to compute if the consumption exceeds 100k'_....

Comment: im just confused on how to compute the usage and consumptions since we were instructed to only use the variables declared on the function

Comment: i forgot to mention that we input our own hrs with scanf hence the usage hours

Answer (score 2):

As a beginner avoid shorthand "tricky" expressions (when you get more experience you will avoid them too). Split the expression into many logical lines which are easy to read and understand. Compiler will most likely emit the same or even better code.

```
double computeTotalCharges(double usage){
    
    double monthlyBill = 0.00;
    
    if(usage > 100000.0) 
    {
        monthlyBill += (usage - 100000.0) * 0.03;
        usage = 100000.0;
    }
    monthlyBill += usage * 0.05;
    return monthlyBill;
}
```

Comment: I will keep that in mind! I edited my question for full context. I am sorry if the first one was a little confusing

Answer (score 1):

Modify your function as below

```
float computeTotalCharges(int usage, float consumption)
{

       float monthlyBill = 0;
       if(consumption > 100000)
       {
           monthlyBill =  (consumption - 100000) * 0.03;
           consumption = 100000;
       }    
       monthlyBill = monthlyBill + (consumption * 0.05);
    
      return monthlyBill; 
}
```